# Getting information from a form (textbox, combobox) and writing to an xml file (PHP/JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: php, javascript

Hi how would i GET information from a form that a user enters into a textbox combobox or w.e
and write it to a xml file.

either HTML javascript or php will be appreciated.

Comment: did you try this in any process?

Comment: You can use the method described in best answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml. Your `$_POST` will become the `$test_array` used in the example. You can modify it a bit to suit your needs.

Comment: @Vikk In this case it isn't really good because the data should be encoded first.

Comment: @Aurelio De Rosa Can you explain a bit more? I guess I'm missing something.

Comment: @Vikk The data sent by the users can contains chars like '<' or '>' and if you put this chars in a xml file without encoding them (in &lt; and &gt;) this will break the xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Well, saying that you have a page with a form like:

```
<form name="form" action="getdata.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="tb" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

your getdata.php (this is just an example of the name) page, which will collect the data and save them in a xml file, should be like this:

```
<?php
   $text = htmlentities($_POST['tb']);

   $doc = new DOMDocument();
   $textareaNode = $doc->createElement("textbox");
   $textNode = $doc->createTextNode($text);
   $textareaNode->appendChild($textNode);
   $doc->appendChild($textareaNode);
   $doc->save("data.xml");
?>
```

Comment: is textarea the same as textbox? like input type=text name="tb"

Comment: @suffix Not exactly. Anyway I update the answer to clarify ;)

Comment: thank you. so when i click the submit button it will goto getdata.php right?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links that can get you started.

- [PHP SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)
- [PHP $_POST](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp)
- [HTML form input types](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)